# Images upload validation is fail

Tags: php, image, validation

I try a lot of script to validate a lot of function to validate user upload within is it an images or not. i try to test it by and it work when i'm loading a file with ext tar, xclx, docx, sql, but it's fail when i'm upload file with extention .themepack. and it seem to fail to validate file size too. here's my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) && ($_FILES['photo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {

        // Get a reference:
        $file = $_FILES['photo'];

        $tmp_name = sha1($file['name']) . uniqid('',true);
        $dest =  $uploads_dir . $tmp_name . '_tmp';

// Validate the file size (1MB max):
        $size = ROUND($file['size']/1024);
        if ($size > 1024) {
            $error[] = 'File u r uploading is too big.';
        }
        $whitelist_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
        $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');

        $filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!in_array($ext,$whitelist_ext) ) {
            $error[] = 'you are entering wrong extension files.';
        }else{
            // Validate the file type:
            // Create the resource:

            if(function_exists('finfo_open')){    //(PHP >= 5.3.0, PECL fileinfo >= 0.1.0)
                $fileinfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

                if (!in_array(finfo_file($fileinfo, $file['tmp_name']), $whitelist_type)) {
                    $error[]  = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
                }
            }else if(function_exists('mime_content_type')){  //supported (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5)
                if (!in_array(mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']), $whitelist_type)) {
                    $error[]  = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
                }
            }else{
                if (!@getimagesize($file['tmp_name'])) {  //@ - for hide warning when image not valid
                    $error[]  = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
                }
            }
            if ( function_exists( 'exif_imagetype' ) ) {
                if (exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']) != (IMAGETYPE_JPEG || IMAGETYPE_GIF || IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
                    $error[]  = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
                } else{
                    if ( ( list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $filename ) ) !== false ) {
                        return $type;
                    }
                    $error[]  = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
                }
            }
        }
        finfo_close($fileinfo);
    }

    //if no errors have been created carry on
    if (!isset($error)) {

        //hash the password
        $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['pass1'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        //create the activasion code
        $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

        try {

            //insert into database with a prepared statement
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (nama_lengkap,username,pass,usertype, email,active,real_pic_name, tmp_pic_name, dateAdded) VALUES (:nama_lengkap, :username,:pass, :usertype, :email, :active, :real_pic_name, :tmp_pic_name,now())');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':nama_lengkap' => $_POST['nama_lengkap'],
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':pass' => $hashedpassword,
                ':usertype' => $_POST['usertype'],
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':active' => $activasion,
                ':real_pic_name' => $photo_name,
                ':tmp_pic_name' => $photo_tmp
            ));
            $id = $pdo->lastInsertId('id');

            //move_uploaded_file($photo_tmp, $uploads_dir . $photo_name);

            if (!(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))) {
                $error[] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }else{
                redirect('add-user.php?action=joined');
                unset( $_SESSION['token'] );
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        }
    }
```

When i'm upload a file with .themepack it can reach till this code:

```
                $error[] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
```

is it because this is the wrong way to check if there's an error?

> ```
>  if (!isset($error)) {
> ```